# No access to AccountChooserOptions.Builder()

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to `AccountChooserOptions`

```java
      Intent intent =
            AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(
                  new AccountChooserOptions.Builder()
                        .setAllowableAccountsTypes(Arrays.asList("com.google"))
                        .build());
```

but `AccountChooserOptions` is not found

[image]

and yet my dependency is up to date is it not?

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;
...
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

[reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.AccountChooserOptions.Builder)

Answer (score 1):

Use the full name `new AccountPicker.AccountChooserOptions.Builder()`.